# Generate Scripts, Works for Views?

Tags: sql-server

I recall once generating a script to insert table values. I used SQL Server to select a database, then right-click to select "tasks ->" then "generate scripts," and got through a wizard to select my table and save the results to a new query window. In the "Advanced" settings I would select "data only" as the Types of Data to Script. And, I recall getting a resulting list of "Insert" statements like:

```
 GO
 Insert INTO myTable Values('a','b','c')
 GO
 Insert INTO myTable Values('1','2','3')
 GO
 Insert INTO myTable Values('1','2','3')
 GO
```

...where the data scripted was the actual data from the table.  I used this to save/repopulate tables that I would occasionally have to update from different locations.

Now, I am trying this again years later and it's only giving me what looks like Schema scripts...? I am defiintely trying to use a view this time, and not a table. My result set looks like this:

```
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 CREATE VIEW [dbo].[myView] AS  SELECT [_Result2801].[_Column3] [Employee], 
 [_E2].[Date] ...
```

Where this "Select" also has some nested Select statements, views...

Why does this look so much different from my expectation? I definitely chose "data only" and not schema. I tried to search whether this works with views, and I keep finding tutorials/documentation that don't answer my question.

Comment: Slight detour but it sounds like you have nested views. This is going to lead to horrific performance problems. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Comment: Yes, sir. There are many performance problems, and unfortunately some may be out of my control as I'm working with auto-generated views/tables from a program that configures SQL views and tables, which has been used for years and caused somewhat of a mess. That's a great link to help me through what I can sift through! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work that way unfortunately, due to the nature of what a view is. Views don't typically persist/contain "data", rather they are a query to access data, and inserting into a view is sketchy at best and flat out doesn't work at worst. Your best bet is to script the underlying tables that the view queries.

Comment: Welp, that answers the question. Thanks!

Comment: My new idea is to somehow create a new DB table temporarily, populate it from the view (INSERT INTO (Select * from...)) and then run this "generate scripts" thing on the table, then save-off the scripts.  I'm actually using this to write test cases, so I want to store this data in a new #temp table anyway, but I want to use my current data setup since it's very representative of all test cases.